# Form Dispose is disposing the calling Form not the form itself

Tags: c#, winforms

I have instantiated a new Form (ViewForm) from another form (MainForm). I opened the ViewForm like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var viewerForm = new ViewerForm("172.19.135.74", _applicationSettings);
            viewerForm.Show();

           
        }
```

In my viewerForm, I need to close that current form

```
 private void VlcMediaPlayer_EncounteredError(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayerEncounteredErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($@"Check your username and password.");
        _password = string.Empty;
        _savedPassword = string.Empty;
        Invoke(new Action(() => Dispose())); // This closes the form but it freezes the MainForm.
    }
```

but I get the message
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.' in the ViewerForm.Designer.cs. So I tried using Invoke

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

The 2nd ViewForm closes leaving the MainForm, but once I get to the MainForm I cannot click on anything.

How do I do this right?

Comment: Don't use `Dispose()` within the form itself. Use `Close()` instead.

Comment: Using Close() gives me the same error.

Comment: When used from where? From a button event handler? That should not be the case. Please show the whole relevant code.

Comment: Change the `Dispose()` back to its original form. You'll only ever want to call it from the parent form. However, you possibly need to use Invoke from `VlcMediaPlayer_EncounteredError` as this might be called on a different thread.

Comment: @PMF Hi. with the edits I made, I can actually close the form but it freezes the MainForm which is the one that created the ViewForm.

Comment: When you show your form, always supply the current form as the owner. Also, *all* UI work should go to the UI thread, that includes messageboxes. `VlcMediaPlayer_EncounteredError` should probably do *nothing* except invoke a method on the UI thread.

Comment: @JonasH "When you show your form, always supply the current form as the owner." Could you give a sample of this? This seems right.

Comment: Just do `viewerForm.Show(this);` See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.  Using the

```
Invoke(new Action(() => Dispose()));
```

gives me the cross-thread exception. I just changed the `Invoke` to `this.BeginInvoke`

Comment: you should not be calling Dispose on the form though